# How do I not show the colum title in a simple table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress with the events manager plugin. There is a table which shows the events as a list. The list ist created with SCOPE. I do not want that the first row (with the title of the colum) is shown, because it's not necessary.

I tried to simply delete the text but then the first row is distorted.

I know this is a really basic thing, sorry. Just started to learn it.

```
th class="event-time" scope="col" style="width: 110px;">when?</th>
th class="event-description" scope="col">what?</th>
```

Comment: You could maybe set `visibility: hidden;` within the `style=`

Comment: that deletes only the cell content, not the row itself. but thanks for the try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ***font-size to 0*** , so that you can hide your column title. This will hide the text but keeps the row as itself.

```
<th class="event-time" scope="col" style="width: 110px;font-size:0px">when?</th>
<th class="event-description" scope="col">what?</th>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response!

It works partially, because when I add it the row is gone but also the 110 px width.

I can try to change the width in the plugin core but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you need something that hides the text "when?"  , but need to keep the 1st row as itself with width 110px?

Comment: I wantet to delete the first row with the cell description but keep the table with its colums intact - so yes, now it's working! you can see that in fact there are now two lines stick together (the line above is slightly thicker), but thats no problem at all for my purpose. So big thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:none` within your `th` tag, like:

```
 <th style="display:none">When?</th>
```

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem and how will this code solve it, to help others understand this answer